# Video chat with fake background and image overlays

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, background-image, overlay, google-hangouts, videochat

I would like to allow users to video chat on my website and be able to choose a background that is an image as well as have images added to corners of the video's viewport. I have seen that Google Hangout API pretty much allows this, but I'm having trouble writing my own Google Hangouts application to allow for this, and their sample replace-the-background application that is on their API's webpage doesn't work all that great.

Does anyone know of an alternative to the Google Hangouts API for this use case? For example, if one user would like to set up the video chat so that it appears that the chat is happening at a coffee shop, the background could be replaced with images of a coffee shop. And then the topic at hand in the current discussion could be summarized by a smaller picture of the topic in one of the corners of the viewport.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, and thanks in advance!

If it makes any difference, this is a Ruby on Rails (Rails 4) application which is already in production. I'm just looking to add this feature.